# Как сделать, чтобы функция принимала произвольное число массивов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Пытаюсь сделать через *args, но видимо что-то не понимаю

```
def bubble_sort(array: list or tuple or str, desc=False) -> list or tuple or str:
    type_array_before_convert = type(array)
    if isinstance(array, (str, tuple)):
        array = list(array)

    compare_function = MAPPING_DESC_WITH_FUNCTION_COMPARE[desc]

    for i in range(len(array) - 1):
        sorted_array = True
        for j in range(len(array) - i - 1):
            if compare_function(array[j], array[j + 1]):
                sorted_array = False
                array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]
        if sorted_array:
            break

    return MAPPING_TYPE[type_array_before_convert](array)
```

Были разные попытки, но всегда получается, что если писать несколько аргументов, то сортировать будет только последний и сразу отваливается флаг desc.

Comment: А что не так? Зачем функции принимать произвольное количество массивов? Если их несколько то пусть функция для каждого будет вызвана. `*args` нужен чтобы можно было, например так передавать `bubble_sort(2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5)`

Answer (score 3):

args как раз и позволяет принять произвольное кол-во неименованных позиционных аргументов. args всегда tuple.

```
def foo(*args):
    print(type(args), len(args), args)

foo(1, 2, 3)
foo(*[1, 2, 3])
foo([1, 2, 3])
```

первые 2 вызова дадут одинаковый результат. второй вызов даст tuple в котором будет list

поэтому передать произвольное число списков можно просто передав произвольное число списков

```
def foo(*args):
    print(type(args), len(args), args)

foo([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1])
```

получится tuple в котором будет 2 списка

про `foo(*[1, 2, 3])`, звездочка в данном случае производит распаковку списка перед передачей аргументов в функцию. к примеру если у нас есть функция которая принимает 3 аргумента и список состоящий из 3-х элементов, то так можно заполнить агрументы не прибегая к обращению по индексам.

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    pass

foo(*[1, 2, 3])
```

ну и так как у текущего метода `foo` есть только обязательные позиционные аргументы, то в случае если передаваемый список будет меньше или больше, то мы получим ошибку. и это можно исправить если мы точно знаем что нам будут передавать список длиной более чем 3 или равной этой длине то достаточно добавить args

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, *_):
    pass

foo(*[1, 2, 3])
foo(*[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

в конце я специально использовал `_` как имя для переменной на выброс.

Что по поводу "если писать несколько аргументов, то сортировать будет только последний и сразу отваливается флаг desc"? Мне трудно вразумить код метода. Если условие `if compare_function(array[j], array[j + 1])` не будет выполнено, то `sorted_array` не станет False, и тогда по окончании вложенного `for` закончится и внешний по `break`. Посмею предположить что условие для `break` на самом деле нужно для вложенного `for`. Ну а про desc должно стать понятно из прочитанного выше.